# Generate Constructor in Visual Studios C# doesn't work...why?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have set all my properties of the class with {get;set;} and everytime i click on generate constructor it gives me this message: cursor must be on a constructor call.  I also can't really find anything about this message.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ISYAbschlussProjektJ
{
    public class Loan
    {
        public string bank { get; set; }
        public double amount { get; set; }
        public double rate { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string phonenumber { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string aktenzeichen { get; set; }
        public string iban { get; set; }
        public string bic { get; set; }
        public string betreuer { get; set; }
        public DateTime deductiondate { get; set; }
        public DateTime startdate { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Comment: show us some code. What have you tried?

Comment: I think it's saying that you need to write a constructor call, e.g. `new MyClass("one", 2)`, and VS can generate a constructor with appropriate parameters.

Comment: what are the paramteres exactly? and where do i add this? thank you :)

Comment: @Nino i have added the code

Comment: Where do you click on Generate Constructor? Are you using Resharper?

Comment: @lokusking Edit> IntelliSense>Generate>Constructor

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the **class constructor** :

```
public class Loan
{
    /* Empty constructor */
    public Loan() { }
}
```

To generate constructor included all the parameters (with **VS 2015**) :

- Select all properties
- Right click / "Quick Actions and Refactoring"
- Generate constructor 'Loan(string,double,double,string,string,...'

Comment: no, i didnt write a constructor because first i want all the parameters to be included and i  was trying to generate it but it is not working..

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just write constructor yourself? Constructor must have same name as enclosing class and does not have return type. In your case, constructor can be

```
public Loan() 
{ 
}
```

If needed, you can pass additional parameters in constructor, like this:

```
public Loan(string bankParam) 
{
    this.bank = bankParam;
}
```

You can have one or more constructors for various scenarios (but they must have different number/or type of parameters). Please refer to [MSDN programming guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) for further explanations.

Also, it is good practice to name properties with capital letter, like `Bank` or `Amount˛`

**EDIT**: since you insist in generation, you can to it like this(I'm testing on VS 2015, should be similar in other versions):

To generate constructor, you have to be on constuctor usage.
So, somewhere in your code (not in `Loan` class) write example of your constructor call, like this:

```
Loan l = new Loan("Erste bank", 10.0, 0.5, "Strasse 1");
```

then you can right click on that line and select "Quick actions and refactoring" (or similar option in your VS), or click on light bulb and select "Generate contructor in Loan". That will generate you 
`public Loan(string s, decimal d, decimal p, string d)` or something like this...

Still, I wouldn't recommend too much of that *wizardry* and code generation because of lack of control, odd variable naming etc etc... But, suit yourself.

Comment: first of all i wanted to use the shortcut to save time because i have 12 params and a few more classes that need a constructor.... also i cant find anything on MSDN

Comment: @jasminrandom I have edited my answer and added extra explanations. Also, look at mehdi's answer to generate constructor with all the properties.